# GeoJson layer under partly transparent tile layer in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, mapping, z-index, layer, leaflet

I have some partly transparent tile layers for features on the map that would cost too much runtime performance drawn as vectors.

To order my layers, I use [`setZIndex`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-setzindex) on them. But it seems like a constraint that GeoJson layers are drawn on top of tile layers, even if their z index is smaller.

Is this a general limitation in Leaflet and how can I bypass it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to create a custom map pane, set its z-index to be above the default GeoJSON pane and add the transparent tile layer to it.

Comment: Can you provide some code examples to your solution?

Comment: @raphael No, sorry. I'm not into web development anymore.

Answer (score -1):

This may or may not work but I recently modified the canvas mask plugin :

https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas

to display approximately 20k+ features in leaflet. Would that work for your purposes?

Comment: I would love to use that but we already decided to go for a tile/vector hybrid, and despite the z index the application already works.

Comment: ah well then, I wish I had an answer for you. Those GeoJSON layers in leaflet are kind of inflexible. Good luck!

Comment: The tiles are already rendered, but maybe I misunderstood your point. Do you suggest using this plugin instead of Leaflet's GeoJson layers? If they support the default GeoJson primitives we could do that.

Comment: yeah that's what I did. I modified it to use image icons and it rendered fast. I had tried the same thing with their GeoJSON layer and I had performance issues.

Comment: I don't want masking. Moreover, I don't have points but polygons. How would I use your plugin for that?